# How to access firestore data in functions onUpdate

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My data:

[image]

My firestore function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.onMessageCreate = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {

     console.log(change.after.ref.parent);
```

So I want to access the `users` collection, but I get:

`TypeError: change.after.ref.parent is not a function`

Comment: Are you sure that error message corresponds with something in the code you've shown?

Comment: yes it corresponds to the last line in the code

Comment: I would expect that message if you were trying to call parent as a function, but you're showing it accessed as a property.

Comment: Here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events (last image) it is being used as a variable

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use a / before users as below.

.document('/users/{userId}')